# API VK user.search получения более 1000 ответов

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $start_time = microtime(true);
  $_POST['count'] = 3000;
  $_POST['query'] = 'директор';

  if( $_POST['count'] <= 1000 ){ // например 1000
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $end = 1;//т.к. за 1 запрос максимум получить 1000 отетов
  }elseif( $_POST['count'] > 1000 && ($_POST['count'] % 1000)!=0 ){ // например 5600 600 оставляем на последний запрос
      $count = 1000;
      $end = ($_POST['count'] / 1000) +1;
      $ostatok = $_POST['count'] % 1000;
  }elseif( $_POST['count'] > 1000 && ($_POST['count'] % 1000)==0 ){
      $count = 1000;
      $end = ($_POST['count'] / 1000);
  }

 $offset = 0;
for ($i=0; $i <$end ; $i++) {
  if(isset($ostatok) && $i=$end-1 ){ // если есть остаток и последняя итерация цикла, заменяем count
     $count = $_POST['count'] % 1000;
  }
  sleep(4); // запрос не чаще раз в 3 секунды
    $url =  "https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?&position={$_POST['query']}&count={$count}&access_token={$_SESSION['token']}&offset={$offset}";
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
    $users_data = json_decode($res,true);
    $result[$i] = $users_data;
    $offset = $offset+1000;// увеличиваем сдвиг 
}
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo round(($end_time-$start_time),5)." сек"."<br>"; //время выполнения 
echo count( $result,COUNT_RECURSIVE )."<br>";//к-во всех записей в массиве
print_r($result);
}
```

Нужно вывести пользователей с определенной должностью. Да, лучше использовать `execute`, но мы ищем легких путей. Проблема в том, что получаем(?) только 1 ответ, который записывает в 0 ячейку. Или проблема в записи в массив ?

Часть массива

```
[982] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 111081690
                            [first_name] => Алиона
                            [last_name] => Хильт
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [response] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 699769
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [response] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 699769
                )

        )

)
```

UPDATE1: 
Проблема с ответом vk, почему-то возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: Обойти ограничение в 1000 результатов можно, указывая другие параметры поиска, например, путём перебора возраста от 14 до 80.

Comment: @AndreyParsadanian, я это и указал в ответе ниже, приведя пример с дроблением запроса "Т.е. например делать 1 запрос - получать мужчин с данной должностью, 2 запрос - женщин, и так далее. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй массив пустой, ибо метод `user.search` позволяет получить только 1000 первых результатов.

> Обратите внимание — даже при использовании параметра offset для
>   получения информации доступны только первые 1000 результатов.

Если все же нужно "обойти" данное ограничение, то из возможных вариантов - только "дробить" пользователей. Т.е. например делать 1 запрос - получать мужчин с данной должностью, 2 запрос - женщин, и так далее.

Да это не эффективно, и более того время выполнения будет довольно долгим, т.к. не чаще чем 1 запрос в 3 секунды.

Способ уменьшить время выполнения - [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute)
Но учтите, что:

> code может содержаться не более 25 обращений к методам API.

UPD. execute для `user.search` не работает, т.е. в 1 execute может быть только 1 `user.search`. В противном случае вернет только 1000 первых результатов.